# How to find if an IHTMLDocument2 is equal to IDispatch document in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, iframe

I have a TEmbeddedWB (https://sourceforge.net/projects/embeddedwb/) with an iFrame in it. I have to find out that a specific HTML Tag is inside that iFrame or not. My iFrame object is a `IHTMLFrameBase2`, while the Tag is a `IHTMLElement`. I know that the `iFrame.contentWindow.document` (which is a `IHTMLDocument2`) is the same as `Tag.document`. But the `Tag.document` is an IDispatch object, therefore the following gives a false:

```
if iFrame.contentWindow.document = Tag.document then ShowMessage('In iFrame')
else ShowMessage('Not in iFrame');
```

I know that the two object is the same, because the Watch List can show their memory address:

[image: Watch List]

But I can't get their addresses from code. What I've tried:

```
Addr(iFrame.contentWindow.document) // Gives variable required error
@iFrame.contentWindow.document      // Gives variable required error
Pointer(iFrame.contentWindow.document)  //Compiles, but gives wrong address
Format('%p',[iFrame.contentWindow.document]) //Compiles, but gives EConvertError
```

Note: If I run line-by-line the addresses that the Watch List is showing change after EVERY line of code, no matter the code affects the WebBrowser or not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [rules of COM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810016.aspx):

> It is required that any call to QueryInterface on any interface for a given object instance for the specific interface IUnknown must always return the same physical pointer value. This enables calling QueryInterface(IID_IUnknown, ...) on any two interfaces and comparing the results to determine whether they point to the same instance of an object (the same COM object identity).

So, ask them both for their `IUnknown` interface, and compare.

```
var
  disp: IDispatch;
  doc: IHTMLDocument2;
....
if (disp as IUnknown) = (doc as IUnknown) then
  ....
```

Comment: Perfect, and simple solution. Thanks :)